# Views are not showing if I replace "include" tag with custom view class tag in layout xml file, why?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-custom-view

I've followed the part "Create compound view" in [this guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#create-compound-view). In one of the activity in my application there is views defined as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- some other subviews... -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <!-- some other subviews... -->

        <include
            android:id="@+id/myHeaderView"
            layout="@layout/view_my_header"></include>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

While the custom `myHeaderView` has its layout defined in a xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/yellowView"
        app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/redView"
        app:layout_heightPercent="40%"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="200%"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Basically it should be looking like this:

[image]

It runs well and the custom view is showing as expected. However, if I replace the `include` tag of the custom view element in the xml with the following one:

```
<com.myDomain.myHeaderView
    android:id="@+id/myHeaderView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

And update my constructors for the custom class `MyHeaderView` as below:

```
public MyHeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context);
}

// some other constructor implementations, which they all call "initView(context)"

private void initView(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_my_header, this, true);
}
```

The subviews (e.g. the yellow view) of the custom header view will become disappeared. I checked with Device Monitor's layout view, seems that the size of the header view as well as its subviews are normal. But for some reasons I don't know, they are not visible.

Am I doing something wrong? I understand that the `include` tag is indicating that I am re-using the layout component defined by the corresponding file, but I would like to have the custom view referenced as class `MyHeaderView` instead of `ViewGroup`, so I can invoke methods defined in it hence updating the views, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put `<include>` inside `<MyHeaderView>` instead of inflating in `MyHeaderView`:

```
<com.myDomain.MyHeaderView
android:id="@+id/myHeaderView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <include        
        layout="@layout/view_my_header"/>

</com.myDomain.MyHeaderView>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've achieved that as you suggested, but are the id attributes duplicated?